# How can I maximise the non-spell healing of this party?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, healing

I have a concept for a group of adventuring do gooders that needs some tweaking. This party will be at level 6 and include a paladin, a monk, a cleric and an arcane caster (I'm leaning celestial warlock) but my goal is to have this group heal the maximum number of *hit points* possible between short rests without using spells.  Use of feats is ok in the character builds, but the healing should not come from magical items.

Given this background information:

How can I get the most healing out of a level 6 paladin?

How can I get the most healing out of a level 6 monk?

How can I get the most healing out of a level 6 cleric?

How can I get the most healing out of a level 6 warlock?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey *How can this specific group of PCs during a short rest maximize their nonspell, nonmagic item-based healing, especially with feats allowed?* sounds like a(n almost?) reasonable optimization question to this *5e* outsider. If it's just the last sentence that's edging this question toward being put on hold, that seems a solvable problem.

Comment: How do you define "maximum amount of healing"?  Total number of hit points?  Most hit points in one / two / X rounds?  Healing on one / two / X targets?  Any combination thereof?

Comment: @Punintended I'd like the most healing possible for the 4 member group between rests. So, per round "nova" healing isn't as important but could still be an interesting metric for assessing the group's healing output.

Comment: @Punintended is correct. While I had assumed *healing* in the question meant *restoring lost hit points*, a broader reading of the word *healing* can include that *plus* fixing all kinds of other negative effects, from parasitic infections to curses. Maybe editing the question so as to limit it to restoring lost hit points would help get the question reopened?

Comment: I am not sure whether this should be 4 questions or not.

Comment: @Szega I don't think so. There are a couple sources of healing which don't stack across multiple characters, so the optimum for the group isn't quite equal to the sum of the individual optimums

Comment: @Szega This is a question about optimizing a party, not four separate characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Four Aasimar walk into a tavern...

Because the use of spells are out, there isn't too much going on. I'll quickly go through each of the classes, all of whom get a feat which I'll cover afterwards. I'll also assume everyone have a Charisma modifier of +3 and that noone other than party members are available or relevant to heal.

- Paladin: All get a pool of 30 hit points to dish which is restored on long rests. In addition, by choosing the Crown oath (SCAG) you can restore 1d6 + Charisma modifier to any number of creatures, once per short rest.
- Monk: Choosing the Open Hand tradition, monks can heal themselves 3×Level=18 per long rest.
- Cleric: The life domain channel divinity restores 5×Level=30 creatures and at 6th level it can be used twice between short rests.
- Warlock: Celestial warlock gets a pool of (1+Level)d6=7d6 healing. Also, they should choose the Pact of the Chain so they qualify for Gift of the Ever-Living Ones (XGtE) which will maximize healing the Warlock gets. (Not included in calculations, because it turns them into a mess.)

This is the non-spell healing available to those classes beyond the expenditure of their hit dice. Then, we have their feats. There is a tiny set of feats which grant healing, however Magic Initiate would do it through a spell, so we're left with:

- Healer: Which by expending a 5 cp use of a healer's kit can have a creature regain 1d6 + 4 + number of hit dice = 1d6 + 10 hitpoints. Each creature can only benefit from this once per short rest.
- Inspiring leader: Not healing per say, but lets you hand out temporary hit points (which does much the same) to up to six creatures.
- Martial Adept: in much the same vain, by choosing this feat and the Rally manouver, you can have one creature gain 1d6 + your Cha mod temporary hitpoints once per short rest.

Note that multiple copies of Healer and Inspiring Leader don't work together, so between your 4 adventurers you should have 1 Healer, 1 Inspiring Leader, and 2 Martial Adept: Rallys. Do note that temporary hit points don't stack, so wait for the old ones to be used up before applying new ones.

If everyone chooses Aasimar as their race (Volo's) they get the Healing Hands feature allowing them to restore hit points equal to level, once per long rest.

To summarise, we get

- 30+18+4×6 = 72 hit points restored per long rest
- 60+7d6+4×(1d6+10)+4×(1d6+3) per short rest
- 4×9+2×(1d6+3) temporary hit points per short rest

Comment: It's UA material but a Way of Tranquility monk gets 10x level in healing. So, 60 hp in this example.

Comment: A dwarven celestial chain pact warlock walks into a tavern.                   The answer is developing nicely.  Is there any advantage to taking the feat Dwarven Resilience. Each dodge action would heal the maximum amount because of the warlock invocation. Dwarven constitution is also high and woul lead to more hit points healed.

Comment: If my math is right, and all the healing goes to the warlock in order to maximize the healing, we are at 235 hit points.  There are also 3 med kits, 3 turn the tide and 6 rallies left for the rest of the group. So, another 93 hit points assuming an average roll of 3 and ability modifiers of +3.

Comment: @Adenine2k To get Dwarven Fortitude you would have to give up the Aasimar feature and the feat slot and it doesn't technically gain you any healing resource, but just lets you access the 'built in' one at a different time. It's also strenous to call it between short rest healing as hit dice aren't fully replenished even on long rests.